# How can I fix a RuntimeError in Python for a discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I've been trying to build myself a discord bot based on a tutorial series that I'm watching. When i try to run the code below, I get a Runtime Error. I left the Token that you need to connect to with the bot out in the last line because I obviously don't want any one to be able to connect to him.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.run("y9QHVpnw5u8aJWYZHMAatZ-nCSrM17YF")
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 295, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000249A4C08E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
PS C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\Python>
```

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Eingeloggt!")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print("Nachricht von" + str(message.author) + "enthält" + str(message.content))

client = MyClient()
client.run("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're copying the bot's token, and not the client secret. Go to the developer portal (discord.com/developers), click on your application, click on the Bot tab, copy the token, and pass it to client.run.

Comment: Thank you dude :) I can't believe I was that retardet and copied the wrong token!

Answer (score 0):

i think it's an error installation:

```
 File "c:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.run("y9QHVpnw5u8aJWYZHMAatZ-nCSrM17YF")
```

and you let your token ^^

try to reinstall the library discord.py and change the token :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the Discord API requires an auth token to connect to the service (it's like the bot logging into the website). You can customize the privacy of your bot during token generation.

I'd recommend you create a token following these instructions:

> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html#discord-intro

If that still doesn't work, double check your bot against the quickstart in the docs:

> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

I'd also recommend you read through the documentation on the Python wrapper for the Discord API here:

> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Good luck!!!